# How do I see success of the following FMDatabase executeUpdate statement?

Tags: ios, sql, fmdb

The following code does not give any error but does not do the insert and I can't figure out why. I am still a novice and wanted to know the best way to see the result of this query or see if there is an error message. I'm sure its something simple like "BOOL success = [database executeUpdate...] then print BOOL. Thanks in advance.

```
if ([database open]) {
    [database executeUpdate:@"insert into CONDITION (condition_id, condition_name, condition_detail, condition_area, condition_date, active) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.condition_id], self.condition_name, self.condition_detail, self.condition_area, self.condition_date, [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt] ];

    [database close];
```

Comment: That's not going to work, as you have five `?` placeholders, but six columns/values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `executeUpdate` method has return value and the `FMDatabase` saved `lastErrorMessage`:

```
BOOL isSuccessful = [database executeUpdate:@"insert into CONDITION (condition_id, condition_name, condition_detail, condition_area, condition_date, active) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.condition_id], self.condition_name, self.condition_detail, self.condition_area, self.condition_date, [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt] ];
if (!isSuccessful) {
    NSLog(@"%@", database.lastErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bannings for your fast and VERY helpful response! This is exactly what I needed and I now see the error message and can move along.